# How to exit a 'for' loop in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, if-statement, cypress

This is the code I'm using:

```
it('Test to stop a FOR loop', function () {
  cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.url().then((url) => {
      cy.log(`**${url}**`);
      if (url.includes('api')) {
        break;  // This fails
      }
      if (url.includes('overview')) {
        cy.log('**The URL includes OVERVIEW**');
        cy.get('[href="/api/table-of-contents"]').click();
      };
      if (url.includes('plugins')) {
        cy.log('**The URL includes PLUGINS**');
        cy.get('.navbar__inner > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(3)').click();
      };
    });
  };
});
```

I want to iterate through several pages and stop when the script meets a specific URL. I have tried using `return` instead of `break`, but that doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to do that?

I have tried:

```
if (url.includes('api')) {
  return;
};
```

But it looks like it doesn't exit out of the `for` loop

Comment: Cypress _really_ does not want you to do conditional testing: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing

You should try to make your tests more deterministic.

Comment: @xdumaine Yeah, I'm aware of that, but then how do I do that validation?

Comment: What validation? It's just a bunch of if statements that seem rather pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the `return` statement in cypress won't exit the loop or function as it behaves differently than in synchronous JavaScript.

I add code below.

```
it("Test to stop a FOR loop", function () {
  cy.visit("https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress");

  function iterate(i) {
    if (i < 5) {
      cy.wait(1000);
      cy.url().then((url) => {
        cy.log(`**${url}**`);
        if (url.includes("api")) {
          // Stop the recursion
          return;
        }
        if (url.includes("overview")) {
          cy.log("**The URL includes OVERVIEW**");
          cy.get('[href="/api/table-of-contents"]')
            .click()
            .then(() => {
              iterate(i + 1); // Continue with the next iteration
            });
        } else if (url.includes("plugins")) {
          cy.log("**The URL includes PLUGINS**");
          cy.get(".navbar__inner > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(3)")
            .click()
            .then(() => {
              iterate(i + 1); // Continue with the next iteration
            });
        } else {
          iterate(i + 1); // Continue with the next iteration
        }
      });
    }
  }

  iterate(0); // Start the recursion with the initial index
});
```

In this code, the `iterate` function is called recursively for each iteration.

This ensures that each iteration waits for the asynchronous Cypress commands to finish before moving on to the next iteration.

The recursion will stop when the desired condition `(url.includes('api'))` is met.

Comment: @Adrid Yes, this doesn't help as jabaa said. I thought the same but it won't work

Comment: I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

But what exactly do you want to test? You've called cy.visit() only once and provided a single URL, so you can't iterate through several pages in this manner. The goal of Cypress is to create assertions that compare two things together and evaluate whether they have failed or passed.